# Gaussian process for machine learnig

Tags: matrices, machine-learning

Here is my question[image]

in the equation 2.11  A is N by N matrix, so there is not feasible if N is large
the textbook say in the euqation 2.12, we only need to invert size n by n.

But I think $K$ is 1 by 1 scalar, since $K=\Phi^T\Sigma_{p}\Phi$ and  $\Phi^T$ is $1 \times N$ and $\Sigma_{p}$ is $N \times N$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like $\Phi$ is an $N\times n$ matrix with columns $\phi(x_i)$ for $i=1\cdots n$. I guess that $n$ is the number of training samples from which you want to learn the function $f$. Thus inverting $A$ which has the same size as $\Phi \Phi^\top$ ($N\times N$) is more computationally expensive than inverting $K$ which has the same size as $\Phi^\top \Phi$ ($n\times n$) when $n<N$.

Comment: This is my impression as well. I'm not sure if it's a fortunate notation of the authors which is noted in the first line: "[Let] $\Phi(X)$ be the aggregation of columns $\phi(x)$ for all cases of the training set." The distinction of the upper case and lowercase phi is noteworthy.

Comment: you are all right. thanks so much